# How do I reload a cached Svg/SvgItem in Plasma5?

Tags: kde-plasma

When testing with `plasmoidviewer`, if you edit your svg, the image will not update when you run the second time after editing it.

```
PlasmaCore.FrameSvgItem {
    imagePath: plasmoid.file("", "images/dragarea.svg")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the cache like so before running plasmoidviewer.

```
rm ~/.cache/plasma-svgelements-*
plasmoidviewer -a package -l topedge -f horizontal -x 0 -y 0
```